# Smallest and largest number array using index?

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a program that asks the user for ten numbers, then outputs the smallest and largest number. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses Scanner
public class ArrayTester {
// begin execution
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare and create array object
    // declare smallest and largest int variables 
    int[] numbers;
    numbers = new int[10];
    int smallest = numbers[0], largest = numbers[0];

    // create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // prompt user 
    System.out.print("Please enter 10 numbers: \n");
    // use for loop to obtain user input
    for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
        numbers[counter] = input.nextInt();
    } // end obtaining input

    // enhanced for loop to find largest and smallest values
    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (i  < smallest) {
            smallest = i; 
        } // end finding smallest
        else if (i  > largest) {
            largest = i; 
        } // end finding largest number 
    } // end finding largest and smallest values

    // for loop to print user input 
    System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "Index", "Input");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, numbers[counter]);
    } // end printing input values

    // print smallest and largest numbers
    System.out.printf("Smallest number: %d\nLargest number: %d\n", smallest, largest);

} // end main
} // end ArrayTester
```

The problem I am having is when the numbers output, it's giving me 0 as the smallest and 9 as the largest. I know this is because of the 10 number array but how would it be fixed to show the smallest integer and largest integer?

Comment: What do you think is wrong, and what have you done to debug it?

Comment: hint hint smallest = i? what is i there?

Comment: @brad `i` is a *value* from the array, since the loop is an enhanced `for` loop, not a normal index `for` loop.

Comment: I just copied the code and tested the program, it works as expected...
The last to lines of the output are `Smallest number: -1` and `Largest number: 300`, which corresponds to my input!

Comment: `smallest` is 0 because you initialize it to 0, by having `int smallest = numbers[0]` *before* you load values into `numbers`. Value of `largest` is correct, as long as user enters at least one positive number. Note: I entered the numbers `4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 4 4` and got `Smallest number: 0 Largest number: 7`. If I enter `-4 -4 -5 -5 -6 -6 -7 -7 -4 -4`, I get `Smallest number: -7 Largest number: 0`. Here `largest` is wrong for same reason `smallest` was wrong in first case.

Comment: oops I missed the syntax for the for loop thanks!

Comment: Just a small sidenote: This might be one of the rare cases, where too much commenting might not be optimal. For instance you comment imports `program uses Scanner`. If you work with a simple texteditor, this might be okay-ish, but if you work with an IDE like Android Studio, the IDE might auto-update the imports and remove or add them. Your comment on the import would be removed then. Also some comments feel too much, if you use an IDE you dont need to comment where the brackets end, the IDE will highlight that. Rule-of-thumb: `Code tells what you do ... comments tell why you do something`.

Answer (score 0):

`numbers = new int[10];`

The above statement initialises the array with all 0s, since you are assigning `numbers[0]` to `smallest`, it will always be `0`.

Also, another way of achieveing this would be by using Java 8's `stream`, e.g.:

```
int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3,10,0};
IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = Arrays.stream(array).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println(summaryStatistics.getMax());
System.out.println(summaryStatistics.getMin());
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line:

```
int smallest = numbers[0], largest = numbers[0];
```

Below this line:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
    numbers[counter] = input.nextInt();
} // end obtaining input
```

You're initializing "smallest" to 0, because your array doesn't have any values yet. Unless the user puts in a negative number, smallest will always be zero.